# Should we strongly encourage foundation questions to include a basic drawing?

Tags: discussion, questions

Thinking of foundation questions, and so I'm reading the history of such question to see what trends I should consider.  I see lots of questions which lack any spatial sense that could improve the quality of answers.

Questions involving the foundation can be more-heavily influenced by conditions.  Should we recommend that images / drawings be posted;

- whether by commenting / monitoring,
- via the tag wiki's first portion
  (comes up in the tag autocomplete when asking),
- or in the FAQ (e.g. more than just this question on meta)

Comment: There's a lot of instances where a question is kind of a waste of time until pictures are uploaded, and that's not exclusive to questions about foundations (i'm taking the most literal definition here). How many times have we seen an OP ask a question, get a brisk obligatory "needs pictures" in the comments, which gives them a bad taste in their mouth, they loose interest and never come back. I don't know how it would be framed but I would be in favor of posters being strongly encouraged to include pictures for their own benefit.

Comment: maybe the SE platform will eventually include a way to score and rank questions, showing a quality level.  This would teach and encourage answerers

Comment: Well I'm sure the oligarchy would argue that's what the +1-1 system is for but the problem with that is it doesn't tell the op why they're being down voted unless accompanied by a comment. What's worse is that unless it's done gently it tends to feel very punitive to a newcomer.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are the accepted way to request more information from the asker.

Beyond that, users post what they think is important.  The trouble really, is that most users lack  experience in the building trades. Because of that, they don't know what information is important.

Unfortunately, there's not much we can do to guide them before they ask the question.